# Prevent CUPS from restarting job on error and continue where it left off instead.

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cups, zebra-printer

I have a Zebra LP 2844 label printer with the EPL2 driver connected to a raspberry pi running CUPS. Sometimes there are errors with my printer such as it randomly shutting off or running out of paper. After I fix the error, instead of it continuing where it left off, the printer restarts the entire job. Is there any way to make it continue printing from the page that it failed at instead of restarting the entire job and wasting paper.

The error handling settings don't seem to address my concern unless there is something that I am missing.